# Server not available to handle this request, either not initialized yet or it has been disposed

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4

This was the issue occurred, when testing the mule application, after successfully deploying in my system.

error-Server not available to handle this request, either not initialized yet or it has been disposed.

But, the same code, by deploying in other systems, without any changes in the configurations, success response could be seen. So, what should be done to resolve the issue.

[image: Response]

Comment: Please add versions used, error log from Mule/Studio in text, no screenshots. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for why not screenshots. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: Maybe this previous answer is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492800/721855

Comment: version is 7.10.0 . no, previous answer is not useful.